# Terminal issues

Tags: macos, terminal

Every single time I open terminal or other programming related program I get this output: "-bash: ‘alias: command not found"

I can't seem to remove / delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually means that either your system administrator placed a command in the global bash config files, or that you have a problem with your personal config files. Run these commands from your terminal to search for the offending "alias" lines:

```
pico ~/.bashrc
pico ~/.bash_profile
```

If you don't see it there, ask your system admin.

Comment: I found it in ~/.bash_profile, so my last question is: how do I delete it? Thanks anyway.

Comment: The pico text editor is pretty simple. It gives instructions on how to use it at the bottom of your terminal screen. The basics are to use the arrow keys to navigate to the line you want to edit, delete the line and press control+o to save the file. Anywhere you see the ^ character, it means the control key.